# Mascara MOEDA {pt-BR} no GridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms

O meu problema é: quero incluir uma máscara com a moeda brasileira em uma coluna do `GridView`.

Estou utilizando o `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, porém quando ponho para rodar, no `GridView` apenas a primeira Linha(Row) aparece a mascara e não nas outras.

Codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DGVPrinterHelper;
using Npgsql;
using PagedList;
using static Operacao.RelatorioBD;

namespace Operacao
{
    public partial class RelatorioGridContaContabil : Form
    {
        public string valorContSql;

        public RelatorioGridContaContabil(string carregaGridRelat)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            valorContSql = carregaGridRelat;
            carregaGridContabil();
        }

        private void carregaGridContabil()
        {
            try
            {
                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(new EmpresaBD().connString);

                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(valorContSql, conn);
                command.CommandTimeout = 190;
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = valorContSql;

                NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                conn.Open();

                DataSet gridSet = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(gridSet);

                BindingList<RelContabil> relcontabil = new BindingList<RelContabil>();

                foreach (DataRow a in gridSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    RelContabil relat = new RelContabil()
                    {
                        Id = a.ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                        RazaoSocial = a.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                        Exercicio = a.ItemArray[2].ToString(),
                        Lucro = a.ItemArray[3].ToString(),
                    };
                    relcontabil.Add(relat);                    
                }

                RelatorioContabilDataGridView.DataSource = relcontabil;

                // Varredura para verificação de empresas iguais + a soma dos valores
                decimal valor = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() && i != j && j != i)
                        {
                            valor = decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                            RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = valor;
                            RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // 2ª Varredura para verificação de empresas iguais, pois à alguns itens que repetem por mais de 3 vezes
                for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() && i != j && j != i)
                        {
                            valor = decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                            RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = valor;
                            RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Insere a máscara nas linhas do código Empresa.
                string EmpresaFormat;

                for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    EmpresaFormat = RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();                    
                    EmpresaFormat = String.Format(@"{0:\00\.0000}", RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(EmpresaFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(EmpresaFormat);
                }

                decimal MoedaFormat;

                for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    MoedaFormat = Decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

                    MoedaFormat =  Convert.ToDecimal(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = MoedaFormat.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

                    RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(MoedaFormat);
                }

                QuantidadeLabel.Text = RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount.ToString();
                conn.Dispose();
            }

            catch (NpgsqlException nex)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog configImpressora = new PrintDialog();
            DialogResult result = configImpressora.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PageSetupDialog pageSetupDialog = new PageSetupDialog();
            PageSettings pageSettings = new PageSettings();
            pageSetupDialog.PageSettings = pageSettings;
            if (pageSetupDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pageSettings = pageSetupDialog.PageSettings;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
            printer.Title = "Relatório Lucro Distribuído";
            printer.SubTitle = String.Format("Data: {0}", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
            printer.PageNumbers = true;
            printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
            printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
            printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            printer.Footer = "Candinho";
            printer.FooterSpacing = 15;
            printer.PrintDataGridView(RelatorioContabilDataGridView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Primeiro problema é que você está usando `RowCount` e não `.Rows.Count` dessa forma ele está percorrendo apenas as linhas que estão sendo exibidas e não todas as linhas da coleção. Mas também não é assim que se formata a coluna.

Para formatar, bastaria definir o `DefaultCellStyle`:

```
RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
```

Mas para isso, a propriedade do objeto tem que ser numérica (decimal).

A Classe deve ser algo assim:

```
public class RelContabil
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string RazaoSocial {get;set;}
    public string Exercicio {get;set;}
    public decimal Lucro {get;set;}
}
```

Como falei, também há outros problemas no código. Recomendo abrir outra questão para resolve-los, mas deixo aqui como ficaria a execução do `NpgsqlCommand`:

```
private void carregaGridContabil()
{
    try
    {
        BindingList<RelContabil> relcontabil = new BindingList<RelContabil>();
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("string conexao"))
        {
            using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(valorContSql, conn))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 190;
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = valorContSql;

                conn.Open();

                using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        relcontabil.Add(new RelContabil()
                        {
                            Id = dr.GetInt32(0),
                            RazaoSocial = dr.GetString(1),
                            Exercicio = dr.GetString(2),
                            Lucro = dr.GetDecimal(3)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        RelatorioContabilDataGridView.DataSource = relcontabil;
        QuantidadeLabel.Text = relcontabil.Count.ToString();
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException nex)
    {
        //tratar ?!
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.

Vou fazer as alterações, assim que tiver um posicionamento, posto aqui.

Comment: Edição sugerida: SOLUÇÃO

Usei o mesmo código, porém fiz pequenas mudanças, segue abaixo.

             `decimal MoedaFormat;

            for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MoedaFormat = Decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                var lucroCampo = RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = MoedaFormat.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = lucroCampo.ToString();
            }`

Comment: você manteve seu código, e só trocou o `.Rows.Count` ? @Andre

Comment: Eu estava fazendo duas conversões na linha onde é implantada a mascara, sendo assim ele estava dando conflito.
Criei a variável 'lucroCampo' para receber o valor com a máscara, depois voltei ela como string no Grid.

OBS: Eu não fiz o teste com o Rowcount, eu alterei para Rows.Count e assim mantive.

Comment: vc tem ideia que esse monte de for é totalmente desnecessário ?

Comment: De certa forma sim, porém é meu primeiro código de peso haha.
Essa experiência vai me ajudar a criar códigos mais objetivos e sem nível McGyver haha

Comment: pois então...isso está muito errado... de qualquer forma o código certo está aí acima, não quero nem pensar em quantos registros são retornados na sua consulta e o tanto de loop que vai ser efetuado literalmente a toa

Comment: Vou começar a postar mais vezes aqui, vou melhorar os meus códigos.
Agradeço a ajuda e também os conselhos.
Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Segue código: (Versão do .NET Framework: 4.6.1)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Valor formatado");

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", 2.1m) });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", 2.2m) });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", 2.3m) });

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar esse formato.